# Scrollview inside scrollview in android

Tags: android

I am having scrollview inside another scrollview. I want to scroll inner scrollview but outer scrollview is only scrolled.how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in scroll view take one layout and add another scrollview in that layout coz scrollview can hold only one child in it. So that inner scrollview can move for what it is holding in it.

Answer (score 4):

```
    sv01 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.popup_sf_event_scroll_01);
    sv02 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.popup_sf_event_scroll_02);

    sv02.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                sv01.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        else 
                sv01.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        return false;
        }
    });
```